# Duplicate gradle configuration java project

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, build, configuration

Is there a way to avoid this duplication in build.gradle?

```
pluginManager.withPlugin('java-library') {
    apply plugin: 'com.github.spotbugs'

    spotbugs {
        toolVersion = '4.5.2'
        ignoreFailures = false
        showStackTraces = true
        showProgress = true
        excludeFilter = rootProject.file(rootProject.ext.excludeFile)
        effort = 'default'
        reportLevel = 'default'
        reportsDir = file("$buildDir/spotbugs")
        maxHeapSize = '1g'
        extraArgs = [ '-nested:false' ] // no jar or zips
    }
```

and somewhere below:
...

```
pluginManager.withPlugin('application') {
    apply plugin: 'com.github.spotbugs'

spotbugs {
        toolVersion = '4.5.2'
        ignoreFailures = false
        showStackTraces = true
        showProgress = true
        excludeFilter = rootProject.file(rootProject.ext.excludeFile)
        effort = 'default'
        reportLevel = 'default'
        reportsDir = file("$buildDir/spotbugs")
        maxHeapSize = '1g'
        extraArgs = [ '-nested:false' ] // no jar or zips
    }
```

I just want to put same configuration in one place.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a single gradle file, and apply this gradle file in where you want:
`apply from: 'your_gradle_file.gradle'`